# Android change theme of new ProgressBar()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar, android-theme

I *want* to change the *theme* of **just ONE** `ProgressBar` so changing the global theme is **not** an option.

Existing code:

```
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(context);
((LinearLayout) v).addView(pb,0);
```

It works, no errors, but uses the default them. How can I change that?

Comment: And how to change all of progressBars in app, from theme( Or style.xml preferentially)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different constructor to set the style:

```
ProgressBar loadingProgressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
```

And if you want to customize the actual appearance (colors, size, etc.) use this:

```
loadingProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mycustomtheme));
```

Comment: I've tried both of those but it still will not change the theme of the default halo progressbar. Here is what I did. `pb.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar));` R.drawable.progressbar being an xml file that I created with the progress bar theme that I want.